# Data amount when copying is much greater than what actually is (22.04)

Tags: networking, hard-drive, samba

I mainly use Ubuntu to copy data from hard drives (via a dock) to a server. Strangely and recently, when copying, instead of showing the actual amount of data, "Preparing to Copy" shows that it's trying to copy terabytes worth of data from a 250 GB hard drive.

Ubuntu correctly shows the amount of data when simply hitting properties and inspecting a folder. Still, when copying that same folder with 11 GBs worth of data to an SMB server, it shows as 500+ GBs when preparing to copy.

I let the process run a few times just to see; it always gets stuck at some arbitrary amount of data before it freezes and doesn't copy any more data.

I initially thought it was some issue with how the SMB server handles the data, but I have other people doing the same job as me (albeit with different Ubuntu versions and docks), and it works flawlessly for them. I'm just confused as this problem arose last week, and I have no idea why. I've already cleanly reformatted my drive (Samsung SSD as ext4) and used different docks, but that didn't fix the problem.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.